# Find $B$ which fulfills $BAA^TB^T=I$, where $A$ is strictly lower triangular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

is it possible to find a matrix $B$ which fulfills:

$BAA^TB^T=I$, where $I$ is identity matrix and $A$ strictly lower triangular?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: $A = O$ is strictly lower triangular yet there is no $B$ which satisfies that equation.

Comment: $BAA^TB^T=(BA)(BA)^T$

Comment: On the other hand, since $AA^T$ is symmetric you can find invertible $B$ such that $BAA^TB^T$ is diagonal. Over the complex you can make the diagonal to be all ones and zeros.

Answer (score 1):

It is even never possible. Say $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. Then, because it is strictly(!) lower triangular, $A$ has rank at most $n-1$. So also $BAA^TB^T$ has rank at most $n-1$. But on the right side of your equation, you have $I$, which has rank $n$.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. It is useful to write it down explicitly for $n=2$. Then either $A=0$, which has no solution, or we may assume that
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\quad 
B=\begin{pmatrix} a & c \cr b & d \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then the condition $BAA^ TB^ T=I$ is equivalent to the equations
\begin{align*}
a^2 & = 1 ,\\
b^2 & = 1,\\
ab & = 0.
\end{align*}
Clearly this has no solution.